# Modifying values in raster on basis of value of overlapping cells in another raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

In ArcGIS 10.1 (advanced license) I have a slope raster, and a raster representing a road network. In the road raster, each pixel is given value 0.5, and the areas outside roads are set to NoData. Now, for some purposes I have to accomplish, I need to half the slope value in those cells that fall within roads. I cannot multiply SLOPE by ROAD rasters because I would end up with NoData in those areas outside the roads.

How can I keep the slope value unchanged for the cells outside the roads?

Comment: Raster calculator Con(isnull(road),slope, slope/2)

Comment: Upon further thought, @FelixIP suggestion proves to be the more straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: @FelixIP Great solution. Please consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using raster calculator expression:

```
Con(IsNull("roads"),"Slope","Slope"/2)
```

In general Con() is a great way to merge/mosaic 2 single band rasters, providing their extents are identical.

Answer (score 2):

My solution has two steps:

1. Multiply  SLOPE by ROAD in **raster calculator**. You're right you get only small part of your data, but here we can go to step 2.
2. Use **mosaic to new raster**, input your slope raster and raster created in step 1. In *Mosaic Operator* field choose *last* (if you input first slope raster) and hit ok.

That tool'll create new raster, which has values from raster created in step 1 in overlapping areas and from slope raster in other places.

Comment: Thank you @ami. It worked, except that after having entered the files in that order (SLOPE first, and ROAD second) I had to select LAST in the "mosaic to new raster".

Comment: @NewAtGis Yeah, my fault, sorry ;) (I've edited the answer)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for your useful suggestion.